# Errors - Do they belong in the logic, or the presentation layer?

Tags: php, error-handling, separation-of-concerns

Regarding function calls, **is it better to give the caller the responsibility of checking if a function worked or failed, or should the error be announced by the function itself?**

The reason I'm asking is because I don't like mixing presentation with logic, however if the caller has to error-check, it can be inaccurate and cumbersome eg.

```
if(!login($username, $password)
{
    echo 'Login failed. Please try again.';
}
```

**The caller has no idea why it failed.** Was the username/password combo wrong, or was it a database connection failure? Or some other unexpected reason?

This would not be a problem if we can error check/throw exceptions inside the functions, because then we would have specific errors at specific points of code eg database connection failures...but that would be mixing presentation and logic. What is the best practice here?

Thank you.

Comment: Failure to authenticate is really not an "error." Receiving incorrect login/password is something to be expected in your program's normal course of operation. The function should return true if the password matches and false otherwise.

Comment: @cleong In this case, yes, but I think that was just an example for a generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally give the caller the responsibility by throwing an exception in the business logic (model) layer. Then, the exception can be caught in the controller (and the error assigned a variable in the view). Some people even like to catch exceptions directly in the presentation layer, but this does not apply well in the case of web development. As long as the exception is only used for presentation purposes in the view, I don't consider it much of a problem, though.

So, I would not do as you did in your simple example, because the caller may not always want an error to be displayed. By handling the responsibility to the caller, he or she has a choice. Also, I don't like echoing content in the business logic (I prefer to throw exceptions and keep the models clean from presentation), but your code was most likely just an oversimplified example.

**Edit:** You could do something like this:

Model:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    if (login failed) {
        throw new Login_Exception();
    }

    else {
        // Set session
        return true;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
try {
    $model->login($username, $password);
}

catch (Login_Exception $e) {
    $view->loginError = 'There was an error logging in.';
}
```

You can then throw different exceptions to indicate exactly what went wrong (e.g. `Wrong_Username_Exception`) and handle it accordingly. Alternatively you could even provide a user friendly reason in the exception's constructor, but in my opinion that would be coupling presentation and logic a little too much.

Comment: he is asking about function / procedures and not oop

Comment: @VladBalmos You are right that he did not mention OOP explicitly. I just assumed that OOP was involved with the layers. However, one can use exceptions like this even if there are no controller/model classes.

Comment: yes, you too are right in that you can mix exception handling and procedural code in php. but somewhat breaks consistency

Comment: I don't see the problem. Exceptions and OOP are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sample code:

```
if(!login($username, $password)
{
    echo 'Login failed. Please try again.';
}
```

... is that the login() function doesn't return enough information for the caller to work with. This is a problem no matter whether the caller is a Web presentation layer, or something else.

A better login() function might return an Object, so that your caller could do:

```
$response = login($username, $password);
if(! $response->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Login failed. " +  $response->getErrorMessage();
}
```

Now your login method is not tightly coupled to the user interface, but you are able to pass a reason for the login failure to the user.

Now, it's valid to say that there is still "presentation" in the login() method, since the text returned by it is quoted verbatim to the user. If you want to be even more loosely coupled, you could define a list of error codes, and have your presentation layer translate those into messages. Or you could return a value that points into a message table. Read up on internationalization; it's the same basic domain.

Answer (score 0):

The first one. The caller should have the responsability of error checking.
If you want to know what kind of error ocured you can rewrite the login function and add a third parameter which will hold a reference to the error, like this:

```
<?php
function login($user, $pass, &$error) {
    // if user or pass wrong
    $error = 'Username / pass wrong';

    // if db failed
    $error = 'unable to connect to db'
};

if(!login($user, $pass, $error)) {
    // do whatever you want with the error
}
```

Better yet, you could use constants for the error types

**UPDATE**

You wouldn't want to show the error withing the function if you are setting sessions or cookies after you have called the function. It will break thins and you'll get notices like: "Headers already sent..."

Comment: But wouldn't that still be mixing presentation and logic, considering the error message is inside the function? If someone wanted to modify what the error message was, they would have to go through the actual code. I like your suggestion of using constants, it would be good to put them in a config file so the user can define what the error message should look like for each scenario in a separate file, much simpler than going inside function logic.

Comment: If you use error codes then you solve the presentation problem